# Como criar um projeto para ler tabelas de um projeto ja existente utilizando GeneXus?

Tags: asp.net, genexus

Possuo um projeto feito em C# com banco sqlserver, quero no meu sistema novo "aproveitar" as tabelas do projeto antigo, como fazer isso com GeneXus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em GeneXus, para importar as tabelas que você já tem no banco de dados, você pode usar uma ferramenta chamada Database Reverse Engineering Wizard.

Na documentação tem uma [guia passo a passo](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?6627) como utilizar (em Inglês)